# Define custom type hint with lists in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, types, python-3.6, type-hinting

I am trying to define a new type hint, however, it will not let me do this in Python 3.6 and I was wondering if there is any way around it. Here is my example code where I want my own class which takes a list as a field:

```
class T(type):

    def __new__(cls, nums):
        return super().__new__(cls, f'T((nums))', (T,),{})

    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.__origin__ = T
        self.__args__ = nums
```

whenever I try to actually use this, I get

`'type' object is not subscriptable`

If I define a custom type hint that does not involve a list, the code works. Is there anyway I can define a custom type hint in python3.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that type hints are for objects (or datatypes). You can not create a custom class inheriting from `type`. If you want to create a new datatype, then simply inherit from `object`. Although, even inheriting from object is not necessary as everything is an object in python but it is generally considered as a good practice.

```py
class T(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.__val = val

  def __str__(self):
    return self.__val

t = T(10)
print(t) # 10
print(type(t)) # <class '__main__.T'>
```